# Material UI button updates its colors too slow

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jsx, styled-jsx

I don't know why the button 'Enable Notifications' updates its colors when switching the theme from dark to light and vice versa way too slow. Here is the entire jsx file (I put it since I don't know what exactly could cause this issue). I've tried to do some changes, for instance, to remove the wrapping Typography element, but nothing happened. I've also changed the variant of the button from primary to secondary, but nothing happened as well - also, I don't prefer this variant at all. The only trick that took effect, but is not suitable for this situation since it alters the look of the button substantially, was to change its variant to either contained or text. Nevertheless, I think this is not coincidentally since in these cases the colors of the button didn't change, therefore, it actually doesn't update its style. Also, I find it very interesting that all the other buttons within the Drawer component behave pretty well, i.e., they respond very fast to a theme shift, even if their background is updated while changing the background theme.

```
import '@fontsource/roboto/400.css';
import '@fontsource/roboto/500.css';
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Drawer from '@mui/material/Drawer';
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import List from '@mui/material/List';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Divider from '@mui/material/Divider';
import ListItem from '@mui/material/ListItem';
import ListItemButton from '@mui/material/ListItemButton';
import ListItemText from '@mui/material/ListItemText';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton'
import GitHubIcon from '@mui/icons-material/GitHub';
import HighlightIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Highlight';
import GroupIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Group';
import AppsIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Apps';
import DevicesOtherIcon from '@mui/icons-material/DevicesOther';
import AccountCircleIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AccountCircle';
import ExitToAppIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ExitToApp';
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { useState } from 'react';

const drawerWidth = 250;

const pages = [ {text: 'users', icon: <GroupIcon />}, 
                {text: 'apps', icon: <AppsIcon />}, 
                {text: 'clients', icon: <DevicesOtherIcon />}, 
                {text: 'admin', icon: <AccountCircleIcon />},
                {text: 'logout', icon: <ExitToAppIcon />} ];

const servers = ['A Raspberry PI', 'Some server'];

const commonButtonStyles = {
  root: {
    '&:focus': {
      outline: 'none',
    },
  },
};

const themeFactory = (isLight) => ({
  palette: {
    mode: isLight ? 'light' : 'dark',
    primary: {
      main: '#3f51b5',
    },
    background: {
      default: isLight ? '#ffffff' : '#303030',
    },
    drawerBackground: {
      main: isLight ? '#ffffff' : '#424242',
    },
  },
  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      styleOverrides: commonButtonStyles,
    },
    MuiIconButton: {
      styleOverrides: commonButtonStyles,
    }
  },
})

const darkTheme = createTheme(themeFactory(false))
const lightTheme = createTheme(themeFactory(true))

export default function App() {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(darkTheme)
  const toggleTheme = () => {
    setTheme(theme === lightTheme ? darkTheme : lightTheme)
  }
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Box sx={{ display: 'flex' }}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <AppBar
          position='fixed'
          sx={{ 
            zIndex: (theme) => theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
            backgroundImage: 'none',
            backgroundColor: '#3f51b5',
          }}
        >
          <Toolbar>
            <Typography variant='h5' sx={{ cursor: 'pointer', userSelect: 'none' }}>
              Naughty pie
            </Typography>
            <Typography sx={{ marginLeft: '0.8rem', flexGrow: 1, cursor: 'pointer', userSelect: 'none' }}>
              @0.0.0
            </Typography>
            {pages.map((element)=>(
              <Button variant='primary' startIcon={element.icon} sx={{ padding: '0.5rem', }}>
                {element.text}
              </Button>
            ))}
            <IconButton onClick={toggleTheme} sx={{ color: 'inherit', }}>
              <HighlightIcon sx={{ margin: '3px',}} />
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton
              onClick={() => window.open('https://github.com/linuspauling1/NaughtyPie')} 
              sx={{ color: 'inherit', }}
            >
              <GitHubIcon sx={{ margin: '3px', fontSize: '1.65rem', }} />
            </IconButton>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
        <Drawer
          variant='permanent'
          sx={{
            width: drawerWidth,
            flexShrink: 0,
            [`& .MuiDrawer-paper`]: { 
              width: drawerWidth, 
              boxSizing: 'border-box',
              backgroundColor: theme.palette.drawerBackground.main,
            },
          }}
        >
          <Toolbar />
          <Box sx={{ overflow: 'auto', display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', }}>
            <List sx={{ padding: '0' }}>
              <ListItemButton>
                <ListItemText primary='All Messages' />
              </ListItemButton>
            </List>
            <Divider />
            <List sx={{ padding: '0' }}>
              {servers.map((text, id) => (
                <ListItem key={id} disablePadding>
                  <ListItemButton>
                    <ListItemText primary={text} />
                  </ListItemButton>
                </ListItem>
              ))}
            </List>
            <Divider sx={{ borderTopWidth: '2px' }}/>
            <Typography align='center' style={{marginTop: 10}}>
              <Button variant='primary' sx={{ p: '0.3rem 0.5rem', }}>
                  enable notifications
              </Button>
            </Typography>
          </Box>
        </Drawer>
        <Button variant='contained'>
          Muie
        </Button>
      </Box>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Material UI have default transition-duration of 250ms in **MuiButtonBase-root-MuiButton-root** class

[image]

you can remove this by adding this style to your button

```
<Button variant='primary' sx={{ p: '0.3rem 0.5rem', }} style={{transitionDuration: '0ms'}}>
              enable notifications
</Button>
```

Comment: Wow! Interesting. Tx.